# Ubuntu 18.04 / 17.10 pulseaudio bluetooth iOS volume control

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control, iphone, bluez, a2dp

I have been struggling to get to control my pulseuadio volume from the iPhone volume slider. I fixed it using this here: [bluetoothd --plugin=a2dp](https://github.com/hadess/CHIP-bluetooth-speaker/issues/8)

But there is no onscreen display that shows this visually. The volume change is happening confirmed with my iPhone.

Let me re-enlist the steps involved.

Step1:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt-get install bluez-tools pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Step 2:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
```

append --plugin=a2dp to the following line

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

as follows

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --plugin=a2dp --compat
```

also per [Baby Bluetooth Steps - Debian / Raspbian Stretch](https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/bluetooth_01_en.html) add --noplugin=sap

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --plugin=a2dp --compat --noplugin=sap
```

Step 3:

Then run the following two commands

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Volume control from iPhone works as expected (even Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) but there's no GNOME OSD showing up. Can someone please help me figure out how to get the gnome to show the OSD/GUI volume slider?

Also, found this for raspberry pi running raspbian : [Super Simple Raspberry Pi Audio Receiver Install](https://github.com/BaReinhard/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install)

Comment: make Step 2: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --plugin=a2dp --compat` adding compatibility with previous version of bluez stack.

Comment: `--plugin=a2dp` is already telling *bluetoothd* to load no plugins other than a2dp; as such, the `--noplugin=sap` bit is unnecessary.